Inconsistent results in SBCL
Consider the following Common Lisp code.
(print (let* ((x nil) (y x)) (setq x t) (and y x)))  ; T
(print (let* ((x nil) (y x)) (setq x t) (and x y)))  ; NIL
(print (let* ((x nil) (y t)) (setq y x) (setq x t) (and y x)))  ; NIL
(defun noop (x) (when x (princ "")))
(print (let* ((x nil) (y x)) (noop y) (setq x t) (and y x)))  ; NIL
(print (let* ((x nil) (y x)) (setq x t) (noop y) (and y x)))  ; NIL

Running the above code in SBCL 2.4.9 in linux, the first line prints T while the remaining lines print NIL. This online SBCL interpreter shows the same results. This is not the case in CLISP, for instance, where all the lines print NIL.
Why am I getting this seemingly strange result?

UPDATE 1: I reported this to the SBCL bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/2092588
UPDATE 2: Apparently, one of the project's maintainers committed a fix for this bug in response to my report. That was really fast!

Looks like a compiler error.

@RainerJoswig, Does that mean that I should report this to the SBCL bug tracker?

That would be a good idea! That would be very helpful. Thanks!

Most likely an optimizer bug. Does changing (DECLARE (OPTIMIZE ...)) settings affect the result?

Happens with DEBUG qualities 0 and 1. Here with macOS 15.2 SBCL 2.4.11 on an M4 Pro.

@Barmar, I am a Common Lisp noob so what you are asking is outside my comfort zone. However, I tried adding (declaim (optimize (speed 0) (safety 3))) at the top of the script above and the result did not change. Does that perhaps answer your question?

yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.

That was a fast fix!

Solved in SBCL 2.5.0
